# Inserting variable into string, not working

Tags: python

So i am trying to put value inside this text

````
fp = str("""```yaml\nThe floor price is {floor_price} ETH.```""")
````

i tried the f string but it gives error

edit: i fixed with f string after trying for long

Comment: use a f-string: `f"""  {floor_price}  """`

Comment: You tried the f string? Can you show how you tried it and which error it gave? Note that it's superfluous to call `str()` on a string.

Comment: `var str="myname"
print(f"hello {myname}"`

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with the plus sign(+)

```
fp = "yaml\nThe floor price is " + str(floor_price) + " ETH."
```